# How can I clean my screened porch?

Tags: cleaning, hardwood-floor, porch, screens

First time home-owner in south east Ohio. My home has a North facing porch with wooden floors, and screened windows. The screens face into a very wooded area, and there is a walk-out to a patio directly beneath the porch.

A few months after moving in and winter ended, I started to see an increasing amount of bugs coming in through the porch if I left the door open, so I stapled fine mesh screen to the bottom of the porch between each cross-member. This has helped nearly eliminate bugs coming in, but I still have an issue with the floor boards of the porch being extremely dusty all the time. I have used a deck brush with hose attachment, and scrubbed only to find after drying the floors still appear dusty.

I have also tried cleaning the screens as best I can, thinking that maybe during a rain storm any dust and pollen on the screens may be getting washed into the porch.

I'm not sure what type of wood the floor boards, and walls are made of, but would it be an okay idea to try a pressure washer on the floors, or would there be a better option?
After cleaning the floors, should I apply some type of treatment to them to help prevent further build-up?

[image: Clearly visible dust]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The curse of living in a wooded area. A pressure cleaner is a great way to clean your wood outdoor floor. Afterwards a stain sealer is a good finishing touch. This won't cure the dust but will sure look nice. A word of caution... stick with a pressure washer with about 1500 psi, you don't want to blast out the wood pulp.